# Track motion onTouch in android

Tags: android

After a user touches a `LinearLayout` called `touchLayout` on the screen, I would like to track the movement of their finger until they release their touch. Most importantly, I would like to find the distance that the user's finger moved during the duration of their touch.

This is what I have so far:

`.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);        
            final TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            Integer xcoorda = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            Integer ycoorda = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                            //**This is where I need something to record distance**
                            Integer xcoordb = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            Integer ycoordb = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            Integer xcoordc = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            Integer ycoordc = Integer.valueOf((int) event.getX());
                            }
            return true;
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

}
```

**EDIT** I would like to find distance rather than displacement. In the way I am looking to do it, a curve between two points should return a larger value than a straight line between the same two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the previous x and y values in a class variable so that you can compare them to the new values from ACTION_MOVE.

```
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(
        new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            private float lastX;
            private float lastY;
            private float total;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    lastX = event.getX();
                    lastY = event.getY();
                    total = 0;
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();
                    total += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - lastX, 2) + Math.pow(y - lastY, 2));

                    lastX = x;
                    lastY = y;
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    //Do whatever 
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: That would be good, but I want to find the overall distance traveled instead of the distance between the start and end value. This way, a curve would return a larger value than a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Use distance formula

```
double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xcoordc  - xcoorda, 2) + Math.pow(ycoordc- ycoorda, 2));
```

Comment: That would be good, but I want to find the overall distance traveled instead of the distance between the start and end value. This way, a curve would return a larger value than a straight line.